# Select view template by model type/object value using Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to store different objects in the same controller content array and render each one using an appropriate view template, but ideally the same view.

I am outputting list objects using the code below. They are currently identical, but I would like to be able to use different ones.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#each App.simpleRowController}}
    {{view App.SimpleRowView class="simple-row" contentBinding="this"}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

A cut-down version of the view is below. The other functions I haven't included could be used an any of the objects, regardless of model. So I would ideally have one view (although I have read some articles about mixins that could help if not).

```
<script>
  App.SimpleRowView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'simple-row-preview',
  });
</script>
```

My first few tests into allowing different object types ended up with loads of conditions within 'simple-row-preview' - it looked terrible!

Is there any way of dynamically controlling the templateName or view used while iterating over my content array?

**UPDATE**

Thanks very much to the two respondents. The final code in use on the view is below. Some of my models are similar, and I liked the idea of being able to switch between template (or a sort of 'state') in my application.

```
<script>
  App.SimpleRowView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: function() {
      return Em.getPath(this, 'content.template');
    }.property('content.template').cacheable(),
    _templateChanged: function() {
      this.rerender();
    }.observes('templateName'),
    // etc.
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can make templateName a property and then work out what template to use based on the content.

For example, this uses instanceof to set a template based on the type of object:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: function() {
        if (this.get("content") instanceof App.Foo) {
            return "foo-item";
        } else {
            return "bar-item";
        }
    }.property().cacheable()
});
```

Here's a fiddle with a working example of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/rlivsey/QWR6V/

Comment: This is a very good answer, but unfortunately, this the case where the view is not added via a handlebars helper but as a class which is picked up automagically by ember. In that case, you are not able to access `content` nor the `controller` (discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337065/how-to-get-any-controller-instance-from-init-method-of-a-view). My solution in this case was to have a method observing the `controller.content` and setting the view accordingly in this function via `this.set('currentView', view)`

Answer (score 16):

Based on the solution of @rlivsey, I've added the functionality to change the template when a property changes, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/ux7Qa/

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: function() {
        var name = Ember.getPath(this, 'content.name');
        return (name.indexOf('foo') !== -1) ? 'foo-item' : 'bar-item';
    }.property('content.name').cacheable(),

    _templateChanged: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('templateName')
});
```

Comment: Note: This does not work anymore.  The view will at times attempt to be rendered when it's being destroyed, throwing an error.