# How to catch and view the JSON response?

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have this following view which I get data from a model and thereafter serialize it into JSON.

**views.py**

```
def polling(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = UserReview.objects.filter(movie_id=request.GET['m_id'])
        serializers.serialize('json', data)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

At the client side I want to show this content now. I'm using jQuery's function `getJSON` to archive this. It won't show anything, and the setTimeout doesn't work as well. But I get a response when I debug it with firebug, it however doesn't call the `alert()` function to view the data. I've been trying to figure out what the problem could be for some time now. So I wonder if there's something wrong with my script?

**javascript**

```
function polling() {
    $.getJSON(  "/polling/", 
                {m_id: {{movie_info.id}} },
                function(data) {
                    alert(data)
                    setTimeout(polling, 5000)
                });
    };
```

Comment: Wow, 10.5 million questions on the entire site....

Comment: @blazemonger Each iteration better answer no? :P

Comment: @Blazemonger it's actually post(question+answer), For example [10000000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999064/ember-js-select-view-template-by-model-type-object-value/10000000#10000000). But still amazing~

Comment: If you debug with firebug, did you get the correct content from the ajax call ? Maybe you are getting a n http error and the callback is not called. Try to use a callback for errors.

Comment: @okm If you say so. I couldn't find the API documentation. ;-)

Comment: @Ferran Thanks for the tip, it seems that the output I get from the view is not JSON, therefore it didn't present me with anything on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general methods that will help you find out what is wrong.

1. Use `console.log` very liberally on the front end to make sure everything is going as planned
2. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Callback functions as suggested in a comment, make sure you at least logg an error
3. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/ set up a debug logger, make sure that you can see what is going on and what django is actually returning as json.
4. http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html Better yet drop this badboy anywhere in your code and MAKE SURE that everything is going the right way.  If your success is not being called ont the front end i bet the error is in django! find out where.
5. You can view the errors in the HTML tab in firebug if `debug=True` or you can just request `/polling/` through your browser and view the django error screen.

using some or any of these should put you in a fine place to solve your problem django dev server makes it an absolute ease to breeze through these errors please do some research and find out the many many debug tools made available to you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to all of this but have you tried to use.

$.ajax
        ({

```
        url: "/Build/AllStatuses",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (buildstatuses)
```

This is how I used to call my json and it seems to work.

Comment: yes, I tried that also. It still won't present the output from the model as JSON. Anyway, it will present a simple httpresponse. So I somewhat think the error might be when I serialize the model into JSON. I'm not sure however.