# Collection of objects of multiple models as the iterable content in a template in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to build a blog application with Ember. I have models for different types of post - article, bookmark, photo. I want to display a stream of the content created by the user for which I would need a collection of objects of all these models arranged in descending order of common attribute that they all have 'publishtime'. How to do this?

I tried something like

```
App.StreamRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        stream = App.Post.find();
        stream.addObjects(App.Bookmark.find());
        stream.addObjects(App.Photo.find());
        return stream;
    }
}
```

where the resource name is `stream`

But it doesn't work. I am using the latest released Ember 1.0.0 rc 2 and handlebars 1.0.0 rc 3 with jQuery 1.9.1 and ember-data.

Probably the way I am trying to achieve this whole thing is wrong. The problem is even if I am able to use the collection of objects of multiple models to iterate in the template, I would still need to distinguish between the type of each object to display its properties apart from the common property of 'publishtime'.

Comment: It's a little compilcated than that, but @twinturbo's example shows nicely how to aggregate separate models into a single array: http://jsfiddle.net/twinturbo/JXFT5/3/

Comment: I am very new to ember.js and am still figuring out the concepts and the fiddle does have a lot of code. So I will go through that, try it out and get back with my findings.

Comment: Don't give up :) Stuff like this is one of the rather complicated things to achive in Ember. If you manage to solve it, it's OK to be ridiculously proud to yourself :)

Comment: @GaborBabicz I would suggest you post your answer in the comments as an actual answer so that I can accept and upvote it if it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) to combine the various arrays and then use Javascript's built in [sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the combined result.

### Combining the arrays and sorting them

computed property to combine the multiple arrays:

```
  stream: function() {
    var post = this.get('post'),
        bookmark = this.get('bookmark'),
        photo = this.get('photo');

    var stream = [];

    stream.pushObjects(post);
    stream.pushObjects(bookmark);
    stream.pushObjects(photo);
    return stream;
  }.property('post.@each', 'bookmark.@each', 'photo.@each'),
```

example of sorting the resulting computed property containing all items:

```
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
  streamSorted: function() {
    var streamCopy = this.get('stream').slice(); // copy so the original doesn't change when sorting
    return streamCopy.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.get('publishtime') - b.get('publishtime');
    });
  }.property('stream.@each.publishtime')
});
```

### rendering items based on a property or their type

I know of two ways to do this:

1. add a boolean property to each object and use a handlebars `{{#if}}` to check that property and render the correct view
2. extend `Ember.View` and use a computed property to switch which template is rendered based on which type of object is being rendered (based on [Select view template by model type/object value using Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999064/ember-js-select-view-template-by-model-type-object-value))

#### Method 1

JS:

```
App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  isPost: true
});

App.Bookmark = Ember.Object.extend({
  isBookmark: true
});

App.Photo = Ember.Object.extend({
  isPhoto: true
});
```

template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in controller.stream}}
      {{#if item.isPost}}
        <li>post: {{item.name}} {{item.publishtime}}</li>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if item.isBookmark}}
        <li>bookmark: {{item.name}} {{item.publishtime}}</li>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if item.isPhoto}}
        <li>photo: {{item.name}} {{item.publishtime}}</li>
      {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
```

#### Method 2

JS:

```
App.StreamItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  templateName: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    if (content instanceof App.Post) {
      return "StreamItemPost";
    } else if (content instanceof App.Bookmark) {
      return "StreamItemBookmark";
    } else if (content instanceof App.Photo) {
      return "StreamItemPhoto";
    }
  }.property(),

  _templateChanged: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('templateName')
})
```

template:

```
<ul>
{{#each item in controller.streamSorted}}
    {{view App.StreamItemView contentBinding=item}}
{{/each}}
 </ul>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/asimel/3/edit) - the unsorted list is rendered with method 1, and the sorted list is rendered with method 2

Comment: This looks almost perfect! But assuming objects of the models have properties unique to the apart from the common properties like name and published time, is there any way to check the type/model of the current object and display properties conditionally based on that?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated than that, but [@twinturbo's example](http://jsfiddle.net/twinturbo/JXFT5/3/) shows nicely how to aggregate separate models into a single array.

Code showing the aggregate array proxy:

```
App.AggregateArrayProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    init: function() {
        this.set('content', Ember.A());
        this.set('map', Ember.Map.create());
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.get('map').forEach(function(array, proxy) {
            proxy.destroy();
        });

        this.super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    add: function(array) {
        var aggregate = this;

        var proxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
            content: array,
            contentArrayDidChange: function(array, idx, removedCount, addedCount) { 
                var addedObjects = array.slice(idx, idx + addedCount);

                addedObjects.forEach(function(item) {
                    aggregate.pushObject(item);
                });
            },
            contentArrayWillChange: function(array, idx, removedCount, addedCount) { 
                var removedObjects = array.slice(idx, idx + removedCount);

                removedObjects.forEach(function(item) {
                    aggregate.removeObject(item);
                });
            }
        });

        this.get('map').set(array, proxy);
    },

    remove: function(array) {
        var aggregate = this;

        array.forEach(function(item) {
            aggregate.removeObject(item);
        });

        this.get('map').remove(array);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, deliberately had to use incorrect Markdown syntax as S.O. does not accept links to JSFiddle without code example in the answer.

Comment: can you quote the code in the answer to avoid the problem? That way the answer is no longer dependent on a random fiddle link on jsfiddle that could go away.