# ember.js - computed property combine 2 hasMany

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a model like this:

```
App.Document = DS.Model.extend
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User')
  contacts: DS.hasMany('App.Contact')
```

What is the best way to create a computed property that will combine the two hasMany relationships like this:

```
people: ( ->
  users.toArray().concat(contacts.toArray()).sort (a, b) ->
    Em.Compare(a.get('name'), b.get('name'))
).property('users.[]', 'contacts.[]')
```

Is there a better way than my rough guess above that will apply sorting and take into account if the record arrays are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think you have to use `property('users.@each')` instead of `property('users.[]')` and change `Em.Compare...` to `Em.compare...` (in lower case)

I've made a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ZMTbj/) to illustrate having models for `User`, `Contact` and `Document`

One of the documents has no contacts associated to it, and one has neither contacts or or users. The `people` computed property looks like this:

```
people: ( ->
  @get('users').toArray().concat(@get('contacts').toArray()).sort (a, b) ->
    Ember.compare(a.get('fullName'), b.get('fullName'))
).property('users.@each', 'contacts.@each')
```

The sorting works fine with the combined arrays.

Note: I don't speak coffee very well; sorry if the syntax is not 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

This is a related solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869936/844923

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/asimel/3/edit)

You can do exactly what you thought of, just by using the special [`@each` key](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/)

Example from the linked example:

```
stream: function() {
  var post = this.get('post'),
      bookmark = this.get('bookmark'),
      photo = this.get('photo');

  var stream = [];

  stream.pushObjects(post);
  stream.pushObjects(bookmark);
  stream.pushObjects(photo);
  return stream;
}.property('post.@each', 'bookmark.@each', 'photo.@each'),
```

And then sort them:

```
 streamSorted: function() {
    var streamCopy = this.get('stream').slice(); // copy so the original doesn't change when sorting
    return streamCopy.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.get('publishtime') - b.get('publishtime');
    });
  }.property('stream.@each.publishtime')
```

Comment: yes, changes to the array cause the whole thing to recalculate itself