# Selecting view type based on model

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of items I'm trying to display with Ember.   For each of these items, I'd like to be able to dynamically select the view type to use to display it based on a "message_type" field in each model.

I currently have something like this, which totally sucks and is not scalable:

```
{{#each message in controller}}

  {{#if message.isImage}}
    {{view App.ImageMessageView}}
  {{/if}}

  .... 

  {{#if message.isVideo}}
    {{view App.VideoMessageView}}
  {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

How can you dynamically select a view based on a model's field in Ember?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a similar question that showed 2 ways to do this: [Collection of objects of multiple models as the iterable content in a template in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866899/collection-of-objects-of-multiple-models-as-the-iterable-content-in-a-template-i/15869936#15869936)

### rendering items based on a property or their type

I know of two ways to do this:

1. add a boolean property to each object and use a handlebars `{{#if}}` to check that property and render the correct view
2. extend `Ember.View` and use a computed property to switch which template is rendered based on which type of object is being rendered (based on [Select view template by model type/object value using Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999064/ember-js-select-view-template-by-model-type-object-value))

#### Method 1

JS:

```
App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  isPost: true
});

App.Bookmark = Ember.Object.extend({
  isBookmark: true
});

App.Photo = Ember.Object.extend({
  isPhoto: true
});
```

template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in controller.stream}}
      {{#if item.isPost}}
        <li>post: {{item.name}} {{item.publishtime}}</li>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if item.isBookmark}}
        <li>bookmark: {{item.name}} {{item.publishtime}}</li>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if item.isPhoto}}
        <li>photo: {{item.name}} {{item.publishtime}}</li>
      {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
```

#### Method 2

JS:

```
App.StreamItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  templateName: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    if (content instanceof App.Post) {
      return "StreamItemPost";
    } else if (content instanceof App.Bookmark) {
      return "StreamItemBookmark";
    } else if (content instanceof App.Photo) {
      return "StreamItemPhoto";
    }
  }.property(),

  _templateChanged: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('templateName')
})
```

template:

```
<ul>
{{#each item in controller.streamSorted}}
    {{view App.StreamItemView contentBinding=item}}
{{/each}}
 </ul>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/asimel/3/edit) - the unsorted list is rendered with method 1, and the sorted list is rendered with method 2

Answer (score 0):

It would probably need some more thought, but here is what I have come up with quickly:

```
var get = Ember.get,
    isGlobalPath = Ember.isGlobalPath,
    normalizePath = Ember.Handlebars.normalizePath;

var getProp = function (context, property, options) {
    if (isGlobalPath(property)) {
        return get(property);
    } else {
        var path = normalizePath(context, property, options.data);
        return get(path.root, path.path);
    }
};

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('detect', function (definition, instance, options) {
    Ember.assert("You must pass exactly two argument to the detect helper", arguments.length === 3);
    Ember.assert("You must pass a block to the detect helper", options.fn && options.fn !== Handlebars.VM.noop);

    var path = '_detect_' + definition.replace('.', '_').toLowerCase();
    context = (options.contexts && options.contexts[0]) || this;
    definition = getProp(context, definition, options);
    instance = getProp(context, instance, options);
    context.set(path, definition.detectInstance(instance));

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.boundIf.call(options.contexts[0], path, options);
});
```

Then you can use a helper like this:

```
{{#detect App.Definition instance}}
    DETECTED
{{else}}
    NOT DETECTED
{{/detect}}
```