# Ember architecture: Grid of components, in arbitrary order

Tags: architecture, ember.js

I'm putting together a dashboard kind of page.

It will have multiple columns, with multiple different kinds of content blocks in each column.

Users can decide which blocks go in which columns, and which ones aren't shown at all.

So I'm looping through a saved list of blocks, and I want to be able to choose which kind of block is shown at each point, based on the saved data about the block.

Right now, my template has duplication because I'm rendering each column separately, doing something like:

```
{{#each block in controller.first_column}}
  {{! ...}}
{{/each}}
{{#each block in controller.second_column}}
  {{! ...}}
{{/each}}
{{#each block in controller.third_column}}
  {{! ...}}
{{/each}}
```

So the controller filters the list of blocks. But now, with just three types of blocks, I'd have to have some kind of if test for the block type as well... not DRY.

I've looked at both `Views` (which don't seem to allow any kind of argument to the view), and `Components` (which don't allow me to customize the `templateName` so I can set which template to use).

What's the proper, Ember-style way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161614/selecting-view-type-based-on-model