# Rewrite url in .htaccess with -`s

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Dear stack overflow members

I have a little problem with my website address, as well as in. Htaccess file I'm trying to make. 
The old url that need to be done is for example:
/index.php?side=read&les=22&title=tets-2-ape-apekatt

I use the following code in. htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

I need to do:

```
/index.php?side=read&les=22&title=tets-2-ape-apekatt
```

to

```
/ID-TITLE.html
```

For example:

```
http://malinpedersen.no/23-how-i-get-it.html
```

the title could be: hello-im-from-stackoverflow or anything you want.

the id has to be recognizable with

```
$page   = addslashes($_GET['les']);
```

that are reading my id for the thread to get the information from.
currently my html href code is: `href="<? echo $adresse;?>/<?echo $id;?>-<?echo $name?>"`

I need it to work, tried to search the web , but no luck.

Could someone please help me with this?

EDIT:

since its could be multiple -`s in the title, would it be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /index.php?side=read&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

possible to make this cleaner?

Comment: Your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183130/php-htaccess-apply-page-title-in-url

Comment: Dear Ali Gajani, thats not the same, but i could not understand it completly. would you be able to support me trought the program called teamviewer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?side=read&les=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

It will read the id and title and silently rewrite it to `index.php?side=read&les=id&title=title`

Comment: i see this. but with multiple -`s in the title it would be hard. would it be something like what ive edited my post to?

Comment: You want everything after the id and before the `.html`?

Comment: well, what i edited it to in my post are working. but is there a way for me to .. make it neater and not so much ugly code ?

Comment: What I posted will rewrite `23-how.html` to `index.php?side=read&les=23&title=how` and even `12-how-i-get-it-some-other-long-title.html` to `index.php?side=read&les=23&title=how-i-get-it-some-other-long-title`. It will work no matter the length of the title.